# Strip nested dict of non zero values

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to strip a nested dict (only 1 level deep eg: `some_dict = {'a':{}, b:{}}` all all non-zero and none values.
However I'm not sure who to reassemble the dict properly, the below gives me a key error.

```
def strip_nested_dict(self, some_dict):
    new_dict = {}
    for sub_dict_key, sub_dict in some_dict.items():
        for key, value in sub_dict.items():
            if value:
                new_dict[sub_dict_key][key] = value
    return new_dict
```

Comment: please provide an example input and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the nested dictionary before accessing it:

```
for sub_dict_key, sub_dict in some_dict.items():
    new_dict[sub_dict_key] = {} # Add this line

    for key, value in sub_dict.items():
        # no changes
```

*(In order for `new_dict[sub_dict_key][key]` to work, `new_dict` must be a dictionary, & `new_dict[sub_dict_key]` also has to be a dictionary.)*

Answer (score 0):

This worked. Shame you can't just assign a nested value without having to create an empty for for each key first.

```
def strip_nested_dict(self, some_dict):
    new_dict = {}
    for sub_dict_key, sub_dict in some_dict.items():
        new_dict[sub_dict_key] = {}
        for key, value in sub_dict.items():
            if value:
                new_dict[sub_dict_key][key] = value
    return new_dict
```